# collapsible rows with bootstrap not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel

I am trying to figure out how to make collapsible columns but for some odd reason, the content is showing on the right of the buttons and pushing from just being columns to multiple rows. I was thinking a `clearfix` would make it right, but I am not 100% sure on how to use it in this situation.

I would like to have it all in one row whether it is collapsed or extended. And when you click one, i just want it to open down, but this is what actually happens:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcwTo_wqt6rR0dOaTFJREIweGs/view?usp=sharing]

But it works with the small frame:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcwTo_wqt6rOHdXRDc5UDV3Zm8/view?usp=sharing]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default row">
      <div class="panel-heading col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion">
            Collapse 1
          </a>
        </h3>

      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">test 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion">
            Collapse 2
          </a>
        </h3>

      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">test 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#collapse3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion">
            Collapse 3
          </a>
        </h3>

      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">test 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#collapse4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion">
            Collapse 4
          </a>
        </h3>

      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">test 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the panels active when in the large and medium resolution and collapsed when in the small?